# String to Date conversion returning wrong value

Tags: java, string, date

I am trying to convert a String into Date... But the return value is wrong.

```
String startDate = "2013-07-24";
Date date = new Date();
try{         
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD"); 
    date = (Date)formatter.parse(startDate);
    System.out.println(date);    
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The desired output is:

> Thu Jul 25 00:00:00 CDT 2013

But the actual output is:

> Fri Jan 25 00:00:00 CST 2013

How does the month becomes Jan from July?

Comment: It returned the right value. You had the wrong expectation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the DD for dd;

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 10):

One issue I see is:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
```

should be:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

`DD` represents Day in YEAR. Read this for more information on [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 2):

Replace `DD` with `dd` to match the date.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

As per the [SimpledateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> **D**  Day in year
>
> **d**  Day in month

Answer (score 1):

Day of the month is made using lowercase 'd', and you're using it uppercase...

Change it to:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

at it will work

Answer (score 1):

Modern answer:

```
    String startDate = "2013-07-24";
    try {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(startDate);
        System.out.println(date);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.out.println(dtpe.getMessage());
    }
```

It prints the same as the input string:

```
2013-07-24
```

Your string conforms with ISO 8601. This is what the modern Java date & time API known as `java.time` or JSR-310 “understands” natively, so there is no need for an explicit formatter. It is also what the `toString` methods of the classes generally produce, which is why you get the same output back. If you want output in a different format, use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

I recommend leaving the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` and friends alone. What you really asked of it was a date that was in July and was the 24th day of the year. Obviously no such date exists, and it’s typical for `SimpleDateFormat` to give you some date anyway and pretend all is fine. I cannot count the questions on Stack Overflow that come out of such surprising behaviour of the outdated classes. The modern API is so much nicer to work with and does a much greater effort to tell you when you make mistakes (which we obviously all do).